# How can I use table-valued function in SQL Server where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

I have a table-valued function and it returns a set of id data. I want to put the function in my query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM caritbl 
WHERE cari_id IN (dbo.fn_AtamaliCariListe(37))
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Im sorry I forgat to mention. I revised my question you can see it now.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you can use this function like a table. Normally you perform your query writing like;

```
select * from XTable x where x.col in (select y.col from YTable y)
```

when you use Table-valued functions also you can do it in the same way;

```
select * from XTable x where x.col in (select y.col from dbo.fn_YourFunction(idparameter) y)
```

Not that your table-valued function ought to return a result with a column named "col"

Answer (score 3):

Just do a SELECT with the function.

```
  --Sample Table
  SELECT 12 AS A
  INTO #Temp

  --Query here
  SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE A IN(
  SELECT [transform].[Maximum] (10,12))
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Aykut's answer is the best answer under most circumstances.  This is to note that the equivalent `join` is more complicated than the `in`.  It would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM caritbl c JOIN
     dbo.fn_AtamaliCariListe(37) as acl(id)
     ON c.cari_id = acl.id;
```

Note the `DISTINCT`.  Unless we know that the function returns unique values, we need it.

Now, there may be cases where the `JOIN` is actually better.  If the function is non-deterministic, it is possible that SQL Server will re-evaluate it repeatedly for each row processed by the `IN`.  I don't know if SQL Server would do this, but it is possible.  A `JOIN` does guarantee that the function only gets evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

You could always join to it.

```
select yourfields
from yourtable join yourfunction on something
where whatever
```

This is logically equivalent to what you say you want to do.